# cross-compiling haskell code through ghc and mingw tools

Tags: haskell, mingw, ghc

I've tried `-fvia-C` and the `-pgm`s, but none of them manage to create an executable, splurting out lots of errors like ``` Warning: retaining unknown function ``L4' in output from C compiler ```.

Comment: Could you provide more details of what exactly you're attempting to do?  Such as, what's your build system/OS/compiler chain, and what is the target arch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GHC can't be used as a cross-compiler out of the box.  The build system has some support for cross-compilation which we're currently working on improving.  For more information, see [CrossCompilation on the GHC wiki](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/CrossCompilation).  I suggest taking further discussion to the glasgow-haskell-users or cvs-ghc mailing lists.