# GHC cross-compiling sources on Linux host for Windows

Tags: haskell, cross-platform, cross-compiling, ghc

Are there any tools/hints/tricks which will enable me to compile application for Windows on Linux host?

I've checked  [CrossCompilation](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/CrossCompilation) page on wiki but did not get is it ready to use yet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [cross-compiling haskell code through ghc and mingw tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517387/cross-compiling-haskell-code-through-ghc-and-mingw-tools)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, GHC does not support cross-compilation yet. The best you can do is install GHC in a VM or Wine.